# javascript loop to display modals on button click not working

Tags: javascript, function, loops

Wrote a Javascript function to display modal on button click that is working perfectly but would have to repeat 56 times. So instead I wrote a loop, but the new function is not working and I'm not sure why.

The original working function:

```
var target = document.getElementById('show1');
var currentOpacity = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#hide1").click(function () {
    $("#details1").hide();
    target.style.opacity = currentOpacity + 1;
  });
  $("#show1").click(function () {
    $("#details1").show();
    target.style.opacity = currentOpacity - 1;
  });
});
```

so instead of:

```
var target = document.getElementById('show1');
var currentOpacity = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#hide1").click(function () {
    $("#details1").hide();
    target.style.opacity = currentOpacity + 1;
  });
  $("#show1").click(function () {
    $("#details1").show();
    target.style.opacity = currentOpacity - 1;
  });
});
var target2 = document.getElementById('show2');
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#hide2").click(function () {
    $("#details2").hide();
    target2.style.opacity = currentOpacity + 1;
  });
  $("#show2").click(function () {
    $("#details2").show();
    target2.style.opacity = currentOpacity - 1;
  });
});
```

repeated 56 times

It's just this:

```
const elements = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 56; i++) {
$(document).ready(function () {
  document.getElementById('hide'+i).addEventListener('click',function ()
{
document.getElementById('details'+i).hide();
document.getElementById('show'+i).style.opacity = currentOpacity + 1; });
document.getElementById('show'+i).addEventListener('click',function () {
document.getElementById('details'+i).show();
document.getElementById('show'+i).style.opacity = currentOpacity - 1; });
});
}
```

But this loop isn't working. Any insight as to why?

Answer (score 0):

well to start off with the bit

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 56; i++) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
```

looks wrong.... it should more likely be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 56; i++) {
```